# Writing both intermediates and results to file using Dask

Tags: python, data-science, dask

I have a data script application that uses dask to go trough a database and produce some intermediates, it than combines these intermediates to produce the result. Now I would like to both write out the intermediates and the result efficiently but as you can see below I have only found a very inefficient way where you compute the intermediates more than ones.

```
import dask.bag as db
from other_functions import *

input = db.read_text(file1)
processing_parameter = parse_mapping_parameters(file2)

intermediates = []
for p in mapping_parameter:
    intermediate = input.map(lambda x: process(x, p))
    intermediates.append(intermediate)

products = intermediates.pop(0)

for intermediate in intermediates:
    products = product.products(i)

result = products.map(calc_result)

for i, intermediate in enumerate(intermediates):
    intermediate.to_textfiles(f'./data/intermediate_{i}.*.txt')

result.to_textfiles(f'./data/result.*.txt')
```

The alternative I see is to write the intermediates to file and then use a separate script to read them into memory again and generate the results but IO wise that also feels inefficient. Is there a better way to do this in dask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it this way:

```
import dask.bag as db
from other_functions import *

input = db.read_text(file1)
processing_parameter = parse_mapping_parameters(file2)

to_compute = []
intermediates = []
for i, p in enumerate(mapping_parameter):
    intermediate = input.map(lambda x: process(x, p))
    to_compute.append(
        intermediate.to_textfiles(f'./data/intermediate_{i}.*.txt', compute=False)
    intermediates.append(intermediate)

products = intermediates.pop(0)
for intermediate in intermediates:
    products = product.products(i)

result = products.map(calc_result)

to_compute.append(result.to_textfiles(f'./data/result.*.txt', compute=False))
dask.compute(*to_compute)
```

Didn't realize the to_text method had a parameter that allows you to get a lazy writer. Once I saw that it was kind of obvious. Not sure about how efficient this is though.